# Trigger function in using angular without button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this jss fiddle :tS2m3 (i didn't know how to add link)

how i can do the same functionality (to check if the entered text is equal to some text)  but with out clicking the button.

i need just to enter "hi" and the show message

thank you so much for helping

Comment: Here is [the link](http://jsfiddle.net/tS2m3/) for others and your fiddle is not angular at all

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the elements in a form element, replace #test with form and listen for the submit event (and preventDefault on the event).

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="test"/><br>
<input type="button" id="txt" value="Submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        var text = $("#test").val();
        var comparingText = "hi";

        if (text === comparingText){
            alert( $("#test").val());
        }
        event.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You just simply need to attach key listener to you input.

[Demo][1]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tS2m3/16